# Linker Command Failed

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
duplicate symbol __Z13createDustVFXPN7cocos2d6CCNodeEff in:
    /Users/SrinivasJ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Race-fahplwvpmjymyegjbzoghrjofgou/Build/Intermediates/Race.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Race.build/Objects-normal/i386/AIBike.o
    /Users/SrinivasJ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Race-fahplwvpmjymyegjbzoghrjofgou/Build/Intermediates/Race.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Race.build/Objects-normal/i386/Bike.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

above error i got. i find the duplicate  method in both class "createDustVFX" 
and i changed method name. its working fine.

but want to know why its given duplicate symbol error.
both class are in different folder. no connection with each Classes.

Comment: Do a search in your code base for "createDustVFX" (`_createDustVFX(cocos2d::CCNode*, float, float)`.

Comment: @trojanfoe, plz read my question, i find that method and changed.. its working fine too. but apples architecture level i need explanation. why its giving that error ?

Comment: Because you have a version of `createDustVFX()` in two different files.

Comment: @trojanfoe, i guess am not explain you corrcetly, i understand that i have same method name in two differnt files....  but why its giving error? i need more architecture level explanation.. both files  are not connected each other...

Comment: That will happen on all architectures, not just OSX.  You cannot have the same symbol in multiple object files.